# Facebook Webhook live data stopped being sent after ad account deactivated

Tags: facebook, webhooks, policy, lead

We have implenented a webhook for one of our clients and they could get their lead_gen notifications in to our CRM, but for some reason fb deactivated their account and ofcourse webhook stopped working, but now they have managed to re-activate their ad account but webhook is not working at all :| We have deleted apps, re-create them, follow all the steps from tutorial, but the thing is only test data (from fb panel to testing ) is being sent to the webhook, no real lead data. is it realed to some policy or are we missing something?